# Property of limits explanation

Tags: limits

Why when we have a sequence $\left\lbrace a_{n}\right\rbrace$ and we know that 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1 \qquad \text{for big enough }n \text{ then } \qquad \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0
$$
Do we have any theorem for this property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We **don't** know that, and we can't, because it isn't true.

Take for example $a_n = \frac{n}{n-1}$, then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac{n+1}{n}}{\frac{n}{n-1}} = \frac{n^2-1}{n^2} < 1$$
however $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1,$$

proving a counterexample.

---

What we **do** know is that if there exists some $c<1$ such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < c$ for all large enough $n$, then $a_n\to 0$. We know this because, if the inequality is true for all $n>N$, and if we know that $k>N$, we have

$$a_{k} < c\cdot a_{k-1}<c^2\cdot a_{k-2}<\cdots <c^{k-N}a_N$$ and this clearly goes to $0$.

Comment: And what's the name of this theorem?

Answer (score 3):

No, we do not have a theorem for that, because the statement is worng. Consider for example $a_n = 1  +\frac 1n$.